# Weighted masking in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have the following task: having two vectors
`[v_1, ..., v_n]` and `[w_1, ..., w_n]` build new vector `[v_1] * w_1 + ... + [v_n] * w_n`.

For exmaple for `v = [0.5, 0.1, 0.7]` and `w = [2, 3, 0]` the result will be

`[0.5, 0.5, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]`.

In case of using vanilla python, the solution would be

```
v, w = [...], [...]
res = []
for i in range(len(v)):
    res += [v[i]] * w[i]
```

Is it possible to build such code within TensorFlow function? It seems to be an extension of [tf.boolean_mask](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/boolean_mask) with additional argument like `weights` or `repeats`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution using `tf.sequence_mask`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

v = tf.constant([0.5, 0.1, 0.7])
w = tf.constant([2, 3, 0])

m = tf.sequence_mask(w)
v2 = tf.tile(v[:, None], [1, tf.shape(m)[1]])
res = tf.boolean_mask(v2, m)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
print(res.eval())
# array([0.5, 0.5, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Love this answer. As I understood by `v[:, None]` you meant the same as `tf.reshape(v, (1, -1))`?

Comment: @СтасЦепа in that case it would be more like `tf.reshape(v, (-1, 1))`.